# Child List from Parent List parameter without duplicates C# VS2013

Tags: c#, linq, list, visual-studio-2013, duplicates

I am working on a small expense tracking program. The idea is to have a list that holds Expense objects that can be manipulated and used to perform calculations.

I was able to create the List without issue and populate it with several dummy expenses. My expenses are grouped by category, Expense.expenseType, to allow me to do calculations for analysis so I am trying to make another List that will store category names and relevant calculations values. The list of category names is meant to remove duplicates but so far I've been unsuccessful at populating it.

My approach for creating the List has been to define a Category class that holds only a string parameter for categoryName and a float for categoryTotal although the latter is initialized to 0.00. I then have a For loop that copies the names into the List and a second For loop that removes indexes based on the name once they've been alphabetized. I've tried different variations of this but ultimately I get either an index that is out of bounds or a reduced but still duplicates list of categoryName.

Really hoping to get some advice so I could move forward with the code. I didn't add the actual code since I'm new to C#/VS and figure I may be approaching the problem all wrong.

Edit 1: Based on the feedback I got, the function I am using is below:

```
public void getCategories(List<Category> passedCategories) 
{
    passedCategories = passedCategories.GroupBy(Category =>Category.strName)
                             .Select(gr => new Category
                             {
                                 strName = gr.Key,
                                 fltTotal = gr.Sum(ex => ex.Value)
                             });
}
```

This function is not working, I have a few points I wanted to clarify and I am sure there are others I missed.

Passed categories is a List of Categories that have three parameters - strName, fltTotal and fltPercent. The latter two are currently set to zero when the whole list is populated via a temp Category. The strName is being copied from an Expense List with many more parameters. Since the Category name will repeat in the Expense List, I am trying to remove all duplicates so I can have just the different categories. I took out var since I am passing the List in, should I not have done this? What am I missing?

Thanks again for the help,

Yusif Nurizade

Comment: Please post your code. Otherwise we have to imagine it...Thanks :)

Comment: If you're new to C# then you should certainly be adding your code.

Answer (score 0):

That you need is something like the following. I say something, because I don't see your code and I have to imagine it. For instance, I don't know the name of the property for the amount of expense. I assumed that this is called Value.

```
// This would be the list of expenses. You have to populate it with data.
var expenses = new List<Expense>();

// Using LINQ you can achieve that you want in a few lines.
// First you group by your data by their categories.
// Then you calculate the total expense for each category.
var statistics = expenses.GroupBy(expense=>expsense.Type)
                         .Select(gr=> new Category 
                         { 
                             Name = gr.Key, 
                             Total = gr.Sum(ex=>ex.Value)
                         });
```

Comment: Im learning linq little by little, looking at questions like this--so groupBy returns an IEnumerable<AnonymousGroup>? Or am i misreading this because the select clause appears to take each group and utilize it. Is it an IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Expense>>? That would actually make more sense.

Comment: Hi Ben. The `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`. In simple terms a sequence of groups. Each group is a collection of objects that have a common key. Yup, it is something like  `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Expense>>` with all the expenses in the same sequence share the same key.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @BenKnoble You are welcome dude. I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: @Christos Thanks so much for the reply! I added the code and hope you can help me clarify the points I am still unsure of.